# Why is my website crashing in my Web.config?

Tags: mysql, asp.net

The Error I'm getting...

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Unable to initialize provider.  Missing or incorrect schema.

Source Error: 


Line 60:       <providers>
Line 61:         <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
Line 62:         <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
Line 63:              connectionStringName="InncZone_CS"
Line 64:              enablePasswordRetrieval="false"

Source File: C:\Users\Clayton\Coding\Innczone\web.config    Line: 62 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

The website works fine on every other page but it's the registration page that's giving me this error.

The Website I try to load.

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Register" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" Runat="Server">
    <br />
    <asp:CreateUserWizard ID="cuwNewUser" runat="server">
        <CreateUserButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-info btn-lg" />
        <WizardSteps>
            <asp:CreateUserWizardStep ID="CreateUserWizardStep1" runat="server" Title="Enter your details">
            </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
            <asp:CompleteWizardStep ID="CompleteWizardStep1" runat="server">
            </asp:CompleteWizardStep>
        </WizardSteps>
        <FinishCompleteButtonStyle CssClass="btn btn-info btn-lg" />
    </asp:CreateUserWizard>
</asp:Content>
```

I've tried searching for the answer a dozen times. Please help.

The Web.config

```
<!--MySql.Web-->
  <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" enabled="true" >
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
             connectionStringName="InncZone_CS"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             applicationName="/"
             requiresUniqueEmail="true"
             passwordFormat="Clear"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="7"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
             passwordAttemptWindow="3"             
             userTableName="web_user"
             userIdColumn="web_userid"
             userNameColumn="web_username"
             autoGenerateTables="True"
             autogenerateschema="true"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <!--passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""-->

    <profile defaultProvider="MySQLProfileProvider" enabled="true" >
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLProfileProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLProfileProvider" type="MySql.Web.Profile.MySQLProfileProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="InncZone_CS" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>
        <add name="FirstName" />
        <add name="Surname" />
        <add name="Email" />
        <add name="DateOfBirth" type="System.DateTime" />
        <add name="ProfilePicture" type="System.Drawing.Image" />
      </properties>
    </profile>

    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider" enabled="true" >
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
        <add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="InncZone_CS" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <siteMap defaultProvider="MySqlSiteMapProvider">
      <providers>
        <remove name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" />
        <add name="MySqlSiteMapProvider" type="MySql.Web.SiteMap.MySqlSiteMapProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="InncZone_CS" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </siteMap>

    <webParts>
      <personalization defaultProvider="MySQLPersonalizationProvider">
        <providers>
          <remove name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" />
          <add name="MySQLPersonalizationProvider" type="MySql.Web.Personalization.MySqlPersonalizationProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="InncZone_CS" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
      </personalization>
    </webParts>
```

I installed MySql.Web and I installed MySql.Data using the Package Manager.
I followed every instruction on mysql tutorial website.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the `type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"` part in your provider config key. It is not in correct schema structure.

You should try with just `type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider"` instead of the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still giving me a different issue... This time with the roleManager: Somewhere here:                                                              "<add name="MySQLRoleProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider" connectionStringName="InncZone_CS" applicationName="InncZone" />"

Comment: Exactly the same error message as last time except now it points out the role provider.