# ASP.NET Upgrade - Unable to check current provider schema

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to update a very old .net site to 4.8 (from a very old versio).

I'm getting this error:

Parser Error Message: Unable to check current provider schema

Source Error:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider" >
  <providers>
     <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=5.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=n" connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""  />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Not really sure what I need to do to solve it.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Been searching for similar issues, but haven't found that much yet.

Comment: Looks like this answer from Atunu Roy: [why-is-my-website-crashing-in-my-web-config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630838/why-is-my-website-crashing-in-my-web-config#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20in%20correct%20schema%20structure.%20You,with%20just%20type%3D%22MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider%22%20instead%20of%20the%20whole%20thing.)